# Как сделать прозрачный фон в ячейке таблицы UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Как сделать ячейку таблицы `UITableViewCell` с прозрачным фоном, чтобы были видны элементы под ней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать прозрачный фон у ячейки таблицы нужно сделать прозрачными цвет ячейки (`backgroundColor`), цвет фона (`backgroundView`) и цвет контента (`contentView`):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// строку выше также можно заменить на эту:
cell.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
```

Для стирания фона самой таблицы достаточно спрятать лишь цвет:

```
myTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

<sub>Перевод ответов и комментариев к вопросу: [How to create a UITableViewCell with a transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008246/)</sub>